# Error in displaying data

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently doing a Displaying data page. My table does not retrieving the data from the database, my end tag `</table>` is unrecognize...

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'testing';

// Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_sched ORDER BY term DESC;") or die(mysql_error());  
?>

<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

<?php
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
?>

<tr>
<td width="20%"> <? echo $rows['subj_code']; ?> </td>
<td width="30%"> <? echo $rows['subj_desc']; ?> </td>
<td width="20%"> <? echo $rows['average']; ?> </td>
<td width="20%"> <? echo $rows['status']; ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
}
</table> 
?>
```

Comment: Hi relentless, i've tried it lately but i still got the same error "syntax error, unexpected '<' "

Comment: relentless says, `echo '</table>'` which is right

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

fix:

```
<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>
</table>
```

edit:
and also change your $rows arrays to $row
from this: `$rows['subj_code'];` to this: `$row['subj_code'];`

Comment: Hello Petros, I've tried it also, it displays the table, but the information is not...